# Не срабатывает UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii2, update

Здравствуйте. Делаю опросник на yii2. Отметил чекбокс - нажал голосовать - счетчики обновились. Это работает, но есть одно "но". UPDATE запрос не срабатывает на счетчиках у которых значение 0, ошибок нет, но и результата нет. Если же у поля будет какое-либо значение отличное от 0, то все хорошо срабатывает. При этом если выполнить нужный запрос в phpmyadmin, то даже с 0 значения обновляются.

Вот код с запросами из контроллера:

```
public function actionPoll($id)
{
    $single = Poll::getOne($id);

    if ($single->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        if ($single->count1) {
            Yii::$app->db->createCommand("UPDATE poll SET count1 = count1 +1 WHERE id=$id")->execute();
        }
        if ($single->count2) {
            Yii::$app->db->createCommand("UPDATE poll SET count2 = count2 +1 WHERE id=$id")->execute();
        }
        if ($single->count3) {
            Yii::$app->db->createCommand("UPDATE poll SET count3 = count3 +1 WHERE id=$id")->execute();
        }
    }
    return $this->render('poll', ['single' => $single]);
}
```

А вот запрос который нормально выполняется в phpmyadmin:

```
UPDATE `poll` SET `count2` = `count2` +1 WHERE `id` = 2
```

Также прикрепляю представление:

```
<?= $form->field($single, 'count1')->checkbox(['label' => '', 'value' => $single->count1]) ?>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть проблема ?

Comment: выставите скриншотом таблицу в phpmyadmin. Поле count nullable?

Comment: Вот http://joxi.ru/J2byXZDCERNMm6

Comment: Можно сделать апдейт таким образом, используя метод updateCounters.

Comment: $single->updateCounters(['count1' => 1]);

Comment: И если используете createCommand, то обязательно наряду с PDO

Comment: Если я вас верно понял, то нужно эту строчку:
Yii::$app->db->createCommand("UPDATE poll SET count1 = count1 +1 WHERE id=$id")->execute(); заменить на эту $single->updateCounters(['count1' => +1]); ? Если да, то ничего не меняется.

Comment: Оно работает, только с теми значениями, которые не 0. А поля с 0 обновляет только в том случае, если убрать проверку чекбокса, но без этого никак

Comment: код чекбокса скиньте, которая находится в представлении

Comment: <?= $form->field($single, 'count1')->checkbox(['label' => '', 'value' => $single->count1]) ?>

Comment: уберите value. метод checkbox автоматом считывает значение

Comment: О вы просто царь, все теперь нормально работает. Спасибо вам большое!

Comment: незачто:) добавьте вьюшку в вопрос, я оформлю ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что Вам не стоит указывать **value** в методе **checkbox**. Это потому, что метод checkbox автоматически считывает данные с модели. Вот как нужно вывести Вам checkbox:

```
<?= $form->field($single, 'count1')->checkbox(['label' => '']) ?>
```

Также хочу отметить, что Вы можете обновлять счетчики следующим способом:

```
$single->updateCounters(['count1' => 1]); //равносильно count1 = count1 + 1
```

В итоге следует также отметить, что если Вы не используете **ActiveRecord**, то Вам следует посмотреть в сторону **PDO**.